# Is changing the color of a cell based on nested conditionals possible?

Tags: excel

I have been trying to change the color of certain cells on my WS that fall outside of an acceptable range. The statement I've been trying to use is,

```
IF(OR('cell'>1.3,'cell'<2.5),'turn red','do nothing')
```

In english, "If a cell is less than 1.3 or greater than 2.5 turn red, else do nothing." I cannot find a resource that guides me to how I can get the cells to change colors. I also have been unsuccessful in creating a statement in the `Conditional Formatting` tab that satisfies my goal. I feel this should be simple, but for some reason cannot figure it out. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how to do it?
EDIT: Also, I have different ranges based on another cell on the spreadsheet. I need this also taken into consideration

Comment: your english version and formula are contradictory

Answer (score 1):

- Select the columns that you want to format
- Click Conditional format --> new rule
- Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- In the formula bar enter the formula `=AND(A1>1.3,A1<2.5)`
- Choose the fill color as red and press OK

[image]

am confused with your formula and your english version. If its the other way, then use the formula `=OR(A1<1.3,A1>2.5)`